# Comparing two arrays to retrieve only exact matches in JSP while preserving the display order in dropdown

Tags: java, jsp

I want to display the **userBrands** as selected elements in the options pane and in the dropdown complete **brandslist** needs to be displayed. When condition --> `brands.contains(brand.toLowerCase().trim())`is checked, the elements bat, cat and batting get displayed instead of only bat and cat.

```
String brands="";
String userBrands[]=new String[30];
String brandslist[]= {"bat", "cat", "ant", "batting", "antenna"};

if(user.get("brand")!=null && !user.get("brand").isEmpty()){
    brands = user.get("brand").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("BRANDS: " + brands);        //here bat and cat retrieved from the database //Output: BRANDS: bat, cat
    userBrands = brands.split(",");
}

for(String brand:brandslist){
    if(brands.contains(brand.toLowerCase().trim())){%>
<option selected="selected" value="<%=brand.trim().toLowerCase()%>"><%=brand.trim()%></option>
    <%}else{%>
<option value="<%=brand.trim().toLowerCase()%>"><%=brand.trim()%></option>
    <%} 
}
```

If I try to use 2 loops as below then the order is not maintained i.e. the selected ones come first in the drop-down and unselected ones afterwards:

```
if(user.get("brand")!=null && !user.get("brand").isEmpty()){
    brands = user.get("brand").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("BRANDS: " + brands);
    userBrands = brands.split(","); 
}

        for(int p=0; p<brandlist.length; p++){
            brandlist[p]=brandlist[p].trim().toLowerCase();
        }
        for(int q=0; q<userBrands.length; q++){
            userBrands[q]=userBrands[q].trim().toLowerCase();
        }

        List<String> masterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> selectedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> unSelectedList = new ArrayList<String>();

        masterList = Arrays.asList(brandlist);

        for(int i=0; i<userBrands.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<brandlist.length; j++){
                if(userBrands[i].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(brandlist[j].trim())){
%>
                <option selected="selected" value="<%=userBrands[i].trim()%>"><%=userBrands[i].trim()%></option>
<%
                }
            }
    }
        selectedList = Arrays.asList(userBrands);

        for(String ms: masterList){
            unSelectedList.add(ms);
            for(String s: selectedList){
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(ms)){
                    unSelectedList.remove(s);
                }
            }
        }
        for(String unStr: unSelectedList){%>
            <option value="<%=unStr.trim()%>"><%=unStr.trim()%></option>
        <%}%>
```

All I want is that only the ones that come from the database through `user.get("brand").toLowerCase()` can be displayed in the options as selected ones (not any extra--like batting in first code snippet) and also the order of display of brands in the dropdown remains same as the original array-->`brandslist[]`. Can the first code snippet do the job with some manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `equals` method to compare values instead of `contains` .Also , in below code i have added extra variable `found` to check if value is there in `brandslist` or not by comparing it with `userBrands` array , and depending on that `options` will be `selected` or not selected.i.e :

```
 <%
    String brands="";
    String userBrands[];
    String brandslist[]= {"bat", "cat", "ant", "batting", "antenna"};

    if(user.get("brand")!=null && !user.get("brand").isEmpty()){
    brands = user.get("brand").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("BRANDS: " + brands);      
    userBrands = brands.split(",");
    }

     //out.println(Arrays.toString(userBrands));

    // to check if value there or not
    boolean found;        
    for(int i= 0 ;i<brandslist.length ;i++){
          found = false;
     for(int j= 0 ;j<userBrands.length ;j++){
        if(userBrands[j].equals(brandslist[i].toLowerCase().trim())){ %>
   <option selected='selected' value='<%=brandslist[i].toLowerCase().trim()%>'><%=brandslist[i].trim()%></option>
       <%
             //value there 
            found = true;
        }


    }
       //value not there found will remain false and below code will get executed
        if(!found){ %>
  <option value='<%=brandslist[i].trim().toLowerCase()%>'><%=brandslist[i].trim()%></option>
        <%}
    }%>
```